# Azure Cache Redis Slow Performance rather than DB query

Tags: azure, azure-redis-cache

We have implemented Azure Cache Redis for our project.
But the problem is Azure Cache query performance is slower than db query.
For a query while Redis response average is 115ms the db query average is 60ms.
For another query while Redis response average is 200ms db query average is 210ms.
I expected redis queries to return around 50ms for all requests.
Is this normal or are we missing any point.
Maybe speed is not the case all the time?

Comment: @TryingToTry If you are looking for an answer specific to the query you are executing, then you gotta provide more info on the setup of your Redis and DB. You also gotta provide details on the source that pulls the data.

Comment: Any update on this?

Answer (score 1):

The performance of AzureRedis cache queries depends on various criteria:

- First, you need to check out the source from where you are querying
  the Redis cache. If the source and Redis cache resource are in
  different regions, there may be a significant network latency.
- The pricing tier of the Redis cache also plays a crucial role in the
  performance.
- Use the redis-benchmark.exe utility to check the throughput and
  characteristics of your cache.
- You can also consider the [scaling link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-cache-for-redis/cache-best-practices-scale) to improve the
  performance of the Redis cache.

Answer (score 0):

Possible reasons why query run time varies:

- Different data volumes
- Different system load
- Different query plans

This also can depend on the type of query. In this case SQL database vs Redis.

A [website](https://dzone.com/articles/redis-vs-mysql-benchmarks) tested this and achieved the following conclusion:

[image: Graph of benchmark timing]

Especially if your request number is large, it's always better to use db and Redis together. Otherwise, both are nearly equal and change in their timings per query.

Related:

- [Why does the same query takes different amount of time to run?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16948164/why-does-the-same-query-takes-different-amount-of-time-to-run)
- [Redis vs mySQL](https://dzone.com/articles/redis-vs-mysql-benchmarks)

Answer (score 0):

We're seeing the same thing.

- Our Azure SQL DB is Standard S1 (20 DTUs) which costs about $48 per month AUD
- Our Azure Redis Cache is C1 which costs about $153 per month

I expected cache calls (mget) to be super fast vs the DB calls, however looking at our application insights map for the last 1 hour, it shows:

- Azure SQL has 8.7k calls averaging 5.1ms
- Redis has 3.9k calls averaging 575ms

I only realised this after having some really slow response times, looking in the app insights data and seeing Redis taking multiple seconds to respond.

It is surprising - it could be the way we're using Redis but I don't know what we're doing wrong. Memory and CPU use is low. Server load seems quite high but if memory and CPU are low, I don't understand what that metric means. Too many operations? The operation count is less than Azure SQL costing 1/3 the price and 100 times faster..

Comment: You mean Standard C1? Because there is also Basic C1 tier for redis.

In the Azure pricing table https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/cache/ it says that C1 has "Low Network Performance", maybe that's it?

And where are you hosting your app? In the same region+availability set as both redis and azure sql db?

I'm really curious if it would improve if you use tier C3 with "Medium Network Performance", but yeah its gonna cost more hahaha

You are using which data structure in Redis? Just key-value pairs?